# How to display and validate textbox based on radio button selected

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this 2 radio buttons based on the radio button selection I should display textbox and also I should validate textbox. If I select the radio button yes and textbox null then I should show the error. With the below code I am only able to show and hide textbox but not able to validate textbox. Please suggest a solution.

Model :

```
public class CustomerModel  
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select subscribe option")]
  public bool Subscribe {get; set;}

  public string Email {get; set;}
}
```

view :

```js
 function ShowHideDiv() {
            var chkYes = document.getElementById("Yes");
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
        }

        $(function () {
            warningel = document.getElementById('lbError');
            $("#radio").submit(function () {
                if ($('#Yes').is(':checked') && !$.trim($('#Email').val())) {
                    warningel.innerHTML = "Please Enter Email";
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
 <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
                    <label class="required" for="subscribe">Email Subsciption</label>
                    <span >Yes : <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="Subscribe" id="chkYes" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" /></span>
                    <span >No : <input type="radio" value="No" name="Subscribe" id="chkNo" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" /></span>
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subscribe)
                </div>
                <div id="dvtext" style="display: none">
                    <label for="email" class="required">Enter Email</label>
                    <div style="width:300px;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
                         <div id='lbError' style="color: red;"></div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: If I add Required attribute on the model the textbox will become required whatever option is select. If I select no radio button I don't want to show the text box as well the textbox is not mandatory if radio button is no

Comment: ahhhh I see now... edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a cleaner solution would be using javascript only to show/hide the textbox and let MVC deal with the validation, that you can obtain just by inheritance from `IValidatableObject`.

Let's say you have a `isValidEmail()` custom method somewhere to check for the provided string:

```
public class CustomerModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public bool Subscribe {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Subscribe && !isValidEmail()) 
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Please enter valid email address");
        }
    }
}
```